# Using optionsCaption in a select tag that uses optgroups

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to get the `optionsCaption` of my `<select>` tag to work.

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: Roles, value: SelectedRole, optionsCaption: 'Select...'">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: Group}, foreach: GroupRoles">
        <option data-bind="value: $data, text:Name"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

When I do this, the `Select...` given in the `optionsCaption` parameter does not show in the drop down list. I need to use `optionsCaption` because I want to set `SelectedRole` back to `Select...` when I put `self.SelectedRole(null)` in the `.js` viewmodel file.

**Edit**

Just to clarify further, the `Select...` must sit outside of the optgroups at the top of the list. I have tried manually setting an `<option>` tag above the `<optgroup>` tag but I can not it to be selected when using `self.SelectedRole(null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there does not seem to be a way to use `optionsCaption` from my understangind (feel free to answer if you know a way that I have not seen and I will mark it as the answer!)

Instead, I used a workaround for this.

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="value: SelectedCrmRole">
    <option data-bind="value:''">Select...</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: CrmRoles -->
        <optgroup data-bind="attr:{label: Group}">
        <!-- ko foreach: GroupRoles -->
            <option data-bind="value: $data, text:Name"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

I created a seperate `<option>` above the `<optgroup>` tag with the text set to `Select...`. From what I understand, the important part is the `data-bind="value: ''`. Now, in the viewmodel when I use `self.SelectedCrmRole(null);`, it will know that this is the null/default value because of that empty value for the option I wanted to be the default.

It may not be the best work around but it is working as necessary! Hope this helps anyone who runs into this problem as well.

Comment: Yeah, that is the way to go. Minor detail, you don't need to use `data-bind` on the dummy (caption) option since it has a static value, you can just do: `<option value="">Select...</option>`.